# Universal Quantifiers and Proofs By Contradiction (Binomial Coefficient)

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic, binomial-coefficients

How do we treat universal quantifiers that appear in propositions with proofs by contradictions? (Example below)

I was looking to prove $(\forall n,k)\ n,k\in \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \binom{n}{k} \in \mathbb{N}$ and thought a proof by contradiction could be a way to do this.

What is the correct way to set up a proof by contradiction for propositions like this? Do we need to flip the universal quantifiers to existential quantifiers?

Let's define $P(n,k):=n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $Q(n,k):= \binom{n}{k} \in \mathbb{N}$, then we have the above written as $\forall n,k \ P(n,k) \rightarrow Q(n,k)$.

Ie, do we use propositions 1 or 2 and why?: $$\exists n,k \ P(n,k) \land \lnot Q(n,k) \ \ (1) $$ $$\forall n,k \ P(n,k) \land \lnot Q(n,k) \ \ (2)$$

Comment: You would assume that there are $n,k\in\Bbb N$ such that $\binom{n}k\notin\Bbb N$ and try to derive a contradiction. Whether this is a reasonable approach to the problem depends on your definition of $\binom{n}k$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but how would we treat the quantifiers, can we just ignore them?

Comment: It's choice (1): we have $\lnot(P\to Q)\equiv (P\land \lnot Q)$.

Comment: @Berci So we switch the universal quantifiers to existential quantifiers?

Comment: @Matt1991: I didn’t ignore them: ‘there are $n,k\in\Bbb N$’ is plain English for $\exists n,k\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Yes, because we negate the statement to prove, and $\lnot(\forall x\,P(x))\equiv\exists x\,\lnot P(x)$.